# Error when trying to work with nested objects with constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a nested object using a constructor:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```
function Car(name){
    this.name.data.CarName = name;
    this.show = function(){document.getElementById("fill").innerHTML = toyota.name.data.CarName;};
}
var toyota;
function functionadd(){
    toyota = new Car("Toyota");
    toyota.show();
}
```

I have looked this up everywhere and can't seem to find an answer and am wondering if I'm making some stupid mistake.
Any help is fantastic, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because object *name* is undefined and there is also no property *data* on it, so you have to initialize *this.name* and *this.name.data* before adding *CarName*:

```js
function Car(name){
    this.name = {};
    this.name.data = {};
    this.name.data.CarName = name;
    this.show = function(){document.getElementById("fill").innerHTML = toyota.name.data.CarName;};
}
```

It's shorter with object litteral:

```js
function Car(name){
    this.name = { data: { CarName: name } };
    this.show = function(){document.getElementById("fill").innerHTML = toyota.name.data.CarName;};
}
```